# Opencv Mog2 Background subtractor: Output is a gray image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am currently trying to use the background subtractor to remove false positives from a detector. Eack link reads in an mjpeg video and the subtractor is applied to each video. The code works and the results is found below:

[image: background subtractor results]

The code for the MoG2 background separator is:

```
    for index, link in enumerate(onlyfiles):
        print(link)
        subtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=20, varThreshold=100, detectShadows=True)
        count=0
        count2=0
        # Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
        # If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        # Check if camera opened successfully
        if (cap.isOpened() == False):
            print("Error opening video stream or file")

        # Read until video is completed
        while (cap.isOpened()):
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                print("Frame detected")
                frame1 = frame.copy()  
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 9, 9, 9)
                mask = subtractor.apply(blurred)     
                cv2.imshow("mask1", mask)
                # Copy the thresholded image.
                im_floodfill = mask.copy()               
                # Mask used to flood filling.
                # Notice the size needs to be 2 pixels than the image.
                h, w = mask.shape[:2]
                mask1 = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)                 
                # Floodfill from point (0, 0)
                cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask1, (0,0), 255);                
                # Invert floodfilled image
                im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)                 
                # Combine the two images to get the foreground.
                im_out = mask | im_floodfill_inv
                cv2.imshow("Foreground", im_out)
                cv2.imshow('Video', frame1)
                cv2.waitKey(25)                 

                # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
                if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

            # Break the loop

                cv2.imshow('Video', frame)  
                cv2.waitKey(25)
            else:
                break

        # When everything done, release the video capture object
        cap.release()
        # Closes all the frames
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In some cases a batch of gray images are outputted as shown below:[image: gray output image]

Why is this occurring and is it due to the history? How can it be corrected?

To determine the occurrence of this, I outputted the number of black pixels.zero implies that the image is gray with pixel value of 127.

```
Frame detected
zero pixels:  0
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414628
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414615
Frame detected
zero pixels:  41465

Frame detected
zero pixels:  0
Frame detected
zero pixels:  413462
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414719
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414720
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414720
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414592
Frame detected
zero pixels:  413932
Frame detected
zero pixels:  412518
Frame detected
zero pixels:  412495
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414221

Frame detected
zero pixels:  0
Frame detected
zero pixels:  412651
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414290
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414490
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414707
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414687
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414689
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414665
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414704
Frame detected
zero pixels:  414583

Frame detected
zero pixels:  0
```

If this project is linked to history parameter, than how can one edit the subtractor to set when images can be collected for capture?

Comment: I think the first matter to address is, is it supposed to output gray images?

Comment: So I did further testing when I drop the history down to 2, it does still occur however the gray images appear after a longer duration. Therefore there is more masked images between the gray images and the results worsen. How can we set the time for it to occur? I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: The reason why this is important since can affect the detector.

Comment: Looks like that happens always on the first frame you feed through it. Kinda makes sense, since at that point there is no history yet. | It would help a lot if you made your code sample a proper [mcve] -- right now there's a LOT of code irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks I see your point and you are right, will update the code now.

Comment: This does not explain why it outputs batches when an object is detected.

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell you what's wrong with code, when you don't show the exact code that produces the output (a sample input file would help too). Right now I don't see anything printing the "zero pixels" line, nor do I see where those blank lines come from. I don't know what `onlyfiles` is, so I can't tell how many times that `for` loop runs... Provide us with a minimal snippet of code that runs on a single file, show exactly what that snippet outputs, and give us an input file (I guess video) which we can run the script on to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experimenting with this Background Subtractor thing. I have the same problem and somehow solved it. I think that you cant apply this some type of loop so you might want to call it beforehand. like in ur case, before the for loop.
Maybe it will help.

Comment: your answer could benefit from more details. please review [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Change the code so that the createBackgroundSubtractor function is called outside of the loop and only reference it inside the loop.

When you call the createBackgroundSubtractor OpenCV creates the BackgroundSubtractor and saves the settings to memory. As the while loop runs it updates the subtractor with a learning parameter.

The gray screen you are seeing is the initial state before any updates, and by running the Create function inside the main loop you are essentially overwriting and resetting it.

Here's some pseudo-code

```
# Create BG Subtraction Algorithm in Memory
subtraction_algorithm = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

while condition:
update_background_subtractor = subtraction_algorithm(frame, learning_rate=0.001)
```

Basically, outside the loop = create settings in memory. Inside the loop = update settings.
If you do 'create inside loop', it overwrites and resets the algorithm leading to the gray (initial state of bg_subtractor) instead of the formatted image.

Here's some implementation of the code from the documentation.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

I.e:

```
subtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
for index, link in enumerate(onlyfiles):
    print(link)
    count=0
    count2=0
```

Comment: it is created once for every video file. that shouldn't be the problem. if you think that it is, please explain.

Comment: Hi Christoph, when the createBackgroundSubtractor is used openCV actually creates it in memory. Referencing it in the loop only updates the function with the learning rate. When it is inside the main loop it keeps recreating the background subtractor overwriting everything. This is why the grey output appears. It is the initial state of the subtractor.

There's some more info in the documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

Comment: so you're assuming those multiple video files are pieces of one longer video, rather than standalone clips? why?